# Trigonometry integration with a bound

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry

So, I want to integrate $\int_\gamma sinz\; dz$ where $\gamma$ is any curve joining $i\to \pi$. Can I say that it is beacause $\int sinz=-cosz$, and $-cosz$ is analytic on the domain containing $\gamma$, so I just need to take the difference between endpoint and initial point?

So, I will have $\int_\gamma sinz\; dz=-cos(\pi)+cos(i)=1$?

Did I do that right?

Comment: Everything up to the last $=$ is right. But $\cos (i) \neq 0$, rather $\cos i = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\cdot i} + e^{-i\cdot i}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{-1}+e) = \cosh 1$, so $$\int_\gamma \sin z\,dz = -\cos \pi + \cos i = 1 + \cosh 1.$$